# Tag driven database for asynchron BI

Tags: database-design, tags, nosql

I'm having a little problem coming up with an architecture for tag driven software I'm designing.

What I want to do is store plain text in database, which is liked to an owner and other entities. The plain text is filled with tags just like Twitters hashtags and should be searchable/indexable.
That can be done application side and as a result I'm gonna have tons of small chunks of data that need to be processed for business intelligens.

No one is gonna ready the plain text it's only about the analysis which doesn't need to be consistent and can be run asynchron.

I know that Twitter uses several databases: Gizzard and Cassandra for tweets and FlockDb for relations.

I don't feel like using a hybrid to accomplish relations and I don't want to build the next social network either. What I need to do though is analytics over all tags in relation to other entities.

How can I solve the hash tag problem, or how can I process the text to make it work?

I'm really searching for a nice solution not just any solution. I really know how to create a schema for SQL.

Thanks for helping me through that database jungle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly standard way for representing tags in the database:

[image]

The application parses the RAW_TEXT, for each identified tag checks if it's already in TAG and inserts it there if it isn't. Then it just connects the post with the tags extracted from it, by inserting into TAG_POST.

Note the order of fields in the composite primary key of TAG_POST - having TAG_ID at the leading edge facilitates efficient searching for posts of a given tag. If you want to get tags of a given post, flip the order. If you want both, create a composite index in the opposite order from the PK.

If your DBMS supports [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), TAG_POST would be a good candidate for it.

---

If your DBMS supports leading-edge index compression (Oracle), consider simply doing this:

[image]

A compressed index will store many repetitions of the same TAG_NAME efficiently, so there is no need to "outsource" it to another table just to save space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not searching for a good schema. I'm more in need of a clever database it self. I need to store millions of tags and sum them up in relation to entities or one another. That doesn't need to be consistent but fast/preprocessed.

Comment: What's the difference between "good schema" and "clever database"? ;) What exactly does it mean to "sum them up in relation to entities or one another"?

Comment: I mean a Database like SQL(row or column based) or document, object or graph based. By sum up, I mean COUNT (in SQL trems).

Comment: @John The model above will let you COUNT rather efficiently. For example (in the second model): `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAG_POST WHERE TAG_NAME = 'sometag'` returns the number of posts tagged with the given tag, and will be executed with just an index-only range scan (and also as predominantly index-only range scan in the first model, but you'll need a slightly more elaborate query with a JOIN). If that's not good enough, use the first model and maintain (via triggers) the current count as a field in the TAG table.

Comment: Could you add that to the answer and expand your answer about how to maintain the model using triggers. That should answer my question pretty good.

Comment: @John No need to repeat the same text in the answer when the comment is plainly visible. As for triggers, you'll need a field such as TAG.POST_COUNT, and then create AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE trigger on TAG_POST that increments/decrements the field appropriately. Just be careful to do that atomically in the context of other possibly concurrent updates - either use locking (`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`), or do it inside a single statement (e.g. `UPDATE TAG SET POST_COUNT = POST_COUNT + 1 WHERE TAG_ID = :NEW.TAG_ID`).

Comment: On Update Triggers are painfully slow. I rather go with a non MVCC database like MyISAM.

Comment: @John It is certainly not true in general that "On Update Triggers are painfully slow". In _this_ particular case, the MVCC mechanism _might_ become a problem if there are many updates within the same transaction, on DBMSes using row-level MVCC (Interbase/Firebird, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, InnoDB, but probably not Oracle which uses a different MVCC mechanism). The obvious solution would be to lower the number of updates, e.g. by using a statement-level (as opposed to row-level) trigger. Or just do the whole work in a stored procedure with **one** update at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Sadly I can't perform it in one query.